# Questions about building a Bayesian network

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

[image]

Example: Suppose we choose the ordering M, J, A, B, E

P(J | M) = P(J)? No

P(A | J, M) = P(A | J)? P(A | J, M) = P(A)? No

How do you know that P(A|J, M) = P(A) is the only condition that A depends on M? Is it possible that only J is dependent on A?

Comment: shouldn't the question read as A is dependent on M. Also the meaning of the line P(A | J, M) = P(A | J)? P(A | J, M) = P(A)? No is unclear to me

Comment: i don't constructing that. it is from https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis520/lectures/bayes-nets.pdf